How can I repair / close this gap on the corner of my [old] house?
I'm excited to find, join -- and contribute -- to this helpful and active community. Gotta start with a question, however, so here we go: How would you close this gap in the corner of my roof? (picture below.)
To me, it looks like the roof needs screws attaching the top metal flange (flashing?) to the bottom one, which I can do, but I'm not sure how best to hold down the roof while I do it, short of adding a lot of weight.
My plan was to have someone stand on it while I added screws, but standing on it didn't change it much. (recruit more people?!)
Did someone now bother attaching it, and moisture has worsened the gap over time? How important is it to replace or repair whatever is bowing beneath the roof?
Much appreciated.


Remove the shingles in the affected area.
Remove the flashing.
Refasten the sheathing to the roof joists. Depending on the condition of the sheathing, it may need to be replaced.
Reinstall the flashing.
Reinstall the shingles.

Concise and helpful--thanks. It gives me some direction ("how to refasten sheathing," and what not. haha).
Thanks again.
